# TDirectionsResult from a Memo

Tags: delphi, gmlib

With the code below I am trying to reload a DirectionsResult back into a TGMDirections.

```
procedure Form2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DR: TDirectionsResult;
  i: Integer;
begin
  DR:= TDirectionsResult.Create(Form1.FDirection, 0);
  DR.XMLData.BeginUpdate;
  for i:= 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    DR.XMLData.Append(Memo1.Lines[i]);
  end;
  DR.XMLData.EndUpdate;
  ShowMessage(Form1.FDirection.DirectionsResult[0].Routes[0].Leg[0].EndAddress);
end;
```

All seems well until the ShowMessage where I get a List out of bounds message.
I take it that the DR has not been created or the Memo has not loaded into the DirectionsResult.

Further adaption has confirmed the DirectionsResult[0] does not exist.

Help with the correction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NickHodges it's part of gmlibrary : https://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a TDirectionsResult to DirectionsResult array programatically, you need to invoke Execute method from TGMDirections object.

However you can do something like this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DR: TDirectionsResult;
begin
  DR:= TDirectionsResult.Create(GMDirection1, 1);
  DR.XMLData.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
  ShowMessage(DR.Routes[0].Leg[0].EndAddress);
end;
```

That is, you can work without problems with your object and you can access to all properties and methods.

Note the assignation between XMLData and Memo.Lines, don't assign line to line because the control of XML is made on OnChange event of XMLData.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks cadetill. My project is up and running well. Just tweaking and experimenting with your library. Version 1.0.0 is working like treat for me. Many thanks for the emails over the last few months.

Comment: Just tried your execute method, works brilliantly. Thanks again.